# How do you say "much better" in Mandarin?

Tags: mandarin

How does one translate the following sentence into Mandarin?

> "Why not Australia? It's **so much better** than America"

Can I use 好多了 to translate "**so much better**" ?

Comment: More context would improve the likelihood of an accurate answer. Why not what in Oz? Oz is better than what?

Answer (score 3):

好多了 means " much better" Your sentence would be:

> "Why not Australia? It's **much better** than America"
>
> 為什麼不是澳大利亞？ 它比美國**好多了**“

For " **so much better**" the translation would be "**好太多了**"

> "Why not Australia? It's **so much better** than America"
>
> 為什麼不是澳大利亞？ 它比美國**好太多了**“

Another way to translate "**so much better**":

> - 比美国好(better than America)
> - 比美国好得多(much better than America)
> - 比美国好得多**了** (**so** much better than America)
>
> *It uses the final particle "了" to increase the emphasis.  The 'so' in "so much better" functions the same way.

Comment: I am not the downvoter, however I doubt the use of 好太多了 in Mandarin. It may be used but since 太 is more often used for negative mood, Chinese will tend to avoid using this to prevent misunderstanding. I think 好多了 is enough to express "so much better".

Comment: If "Australia" is part of a suggestion, I would say "澳大利亚怎么样？比美国好得多得多。"

Comment: 比美国好得多得多 is not grammatically correct. As for your suggestion, please see my edited  answer.

Answer (score 1):

Without more detail I made up this little chat:

你毕业后要做什么？
我去美国找工作。
为什么选了美国？澳大利亚比美国更好。

Exactly how you say 'much better' will of course depend on the context.

There is nothing wrong with Tang Ho's answer, why the down vote?

Comment: *There is nothing wrong with Tang Ho's answer, why the down vote?* - May be some people dislike the example sentence I made up suggested America is not the best in everything; may be some people dislike the fact that I didn't use simplified characters.